# How do I take the mean of the same element across multiple lists?

Tags: r, list

I have many lists contained within a larger list. I want to take the mean of the same entry in each of the lists.

Since I have many lists (100 plus) I want to be able to take the mean of all these lists by using 1:100 like I would for vector entries.

Here is some example, non working code.

```
## Make two lists
list_1 <- list()
list_1[[1]] <- 2


list_2 <- list()
list_2[[1]] <- 4

##Make a larger list to put the lists in
big_list <- list()

## Add lists to a larger list
big_list[[1]] <- list_1
big_list[[2]] <- list_2

## This doesn't work
mean(big_list[[1]][1], big_list[[2]][1], na.rm=TRUE)

## This does not work, but it is what I want
mean(big_list[[1:2]][1])
```

Comment: `mean(unlist(big_list))` ?.  Note that `x` argument is a single argument in `mean`.  So, your first attempt may not work even if you do `[[1]]` to extract the innner list.  You may need to `c`oncatenate i.e. `mean(c(big_list[[1]][[1]], big_list[[2]][[1]]))#
[1] 3`

Comment: If you have several inner list element and want to select the first `mean(sapply(big_list, "[[", 1))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getElement` inside `sapply` to pick out a vector comprising the first (or any specified) element from each sub-list:

```r
sapply(big_list, getElement, 1)
#> [1] 2 4
```

and therefore

```r
mean(sapply(big_list, getElement, 1))
#> [1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

We could combine `flatten` from `purrr` package with `unlist`:

```
library(purrr)

  
x <- unlist(flatten(big_list))
x      
mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
```

```
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach will do it as well:

```
sapply(1:length(big_list[[1]]), function(i) mean(sapply(big_list, function(x) x[[i]]), na.rm = TRUE))
```